# How to manage user login with a webserver in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, session, authentication

I'm building an app that performs similar functionality that one website does: register, login, submit order, view orders and etc. Now, do I have to do anything explicitly in order to get things working?

After successful login, a webserver establishes a session and sesssion ID and related session info is written to related cookie. IMHO, I just need to call webservice with login credentials and then the rest will be done implicitly. After successful login, every requested user page from user area will be checked with sent cookies and session file at server side. So, do I have to do anything else in order to get into secure area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to send the value to verify the user to the webserver.. and u can keep the session alive in iPhone using NSuserdefault..

U might want to encrypt the sensitive data send over the network such as username and password.

Comment: So, does cookie get deleted after app goes to background or gets killed? Do you mean that if a session is started and relative cookies are created then I need explicitly save cookie data somewhere else, for example to NSUserDefaults? Why?

Comment: First of all, how do u plan to use cookies in IOS? As for me , I saved everything to NSUserDefaults.. It acted like cookies and also session.. When I don need it anymore, I just remove it..

Answer (score 1):

Agree with what @sicKo has said. Remember, sending data over wireless network is not secure. Do be careful on the transactions when money and authentication involved.

In addition to what @sicKo has said, you may now consider the coming iOS5, store the value at iCloud.